# Flex: Determining number of lines a spark text area can hold without overflowing

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, textarea, paging

I want to implement paging in a spark text area. For that I want to find out the number of lines a spark textArea can hold before the scrollbars appear and just feed that much lines to the text area.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/13/determining-the-number-of-lines-in-a-spark-richeditabletext-control-in-flex-4/

Answer (score 0):

The number of lines a TextArea can hold before a vertical ScrollBar appear is determinated by the heightInLines property.

The code

```
var number_of_lines:int=textArea.heightInLines;
```

will return inside the variable number_of_lines the number of lines you are looking for, and textArea is the id of the TextArea object you are checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numLines:int=t.heightInLines;

var numChars:int=t.widthInChars;
```

The documentation:

> spark.components.TextArea.heightInLines():Number The default height of
>   the control, measured in lines.  The control's formatting styles, such
>   as fontSize and lineHeight, are used to calculate the line height in
>   pixels.
>
> You would, for example, set this property to 5 if you want the height
>   of the RichEditableText to be sufficient to display five lines of
>   text.
>
> If this property is NaN (the default), then the component's default
>   height will be determined from the text to be displayed.
>
> This property will be ignored if you specify an explicit height, a
>   percent height, or both top and bottom constraints.
>
> RichEditableText's measure() method uses widthInChars and
>   heightInLines to determine the measuredWidth and measuredHeight. These
>   are similar to the cols and rows of an HTML TextArea.
>
> Since both widthInChars and heightInLines default to NaN,
>   RichTextEditable "autosizes" by default: it starts out very small if
>   it has no text, grows in width as you type, and grows in height when
>   you press Enter to start a new line.